# how to concat a letter and a number in php

Tags: php, mysql

My PHP code:

```
$dbquery="create view vdata as select concat('P','$id') as id,company_name,contact_person,phone,address,email,quantity,area,mode_of_payment,cost from data order by id DESC;";

$dbquery1="select * from vdata order by id DESC; ";

$result1=mysql_query($dbquery1,$db)or die("cant query 1");
```

the id should be like P1. but  it isn't working.it shows id=1.

Comment: it should be `concat('P',$id) as id`

Comment: thank you, i tried this too and it shows the same result.

Answer (score 0):

you can just do:

```
$dbquery="create view vdata as select P".$id." as id,company_name,contact_person,phone,address,email,quantity,area,mode_of_payment,cost from data order by id DESC;";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no code which executes the contents of `$dbquery`, so your view doesn't exist or probably exists in an older version which is different from what you want

Answer (score -2):

```
$dbquery="create view vdata as select concat('P',id) as 
id,company_name,contact_person,phone,address,email,quantity,area,mode_of_payment,cost 
from data order by id DESC;";
```

mysql_query($dbquery,$db)or die("cant query view");